# Main file is run multiple times from worker processes in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process

I am using cluster.fork() to spawn worker processes in Node.js. I had my app functioning when all of a sudden I started getting strange errors related to the main.js file I use to startup my app being run multiple times. Here are my files:

*children.js*

```
const cluster = require('cluster');
if (cluster.isMaster) {
    console.log('starting master')
    const spawnWorker = function () {
        let worker = cluster.fork();
        return worker
    }

    exports.spawn = function (cnt) {
        for (let i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
            console.log('spawning worker.....')
            spawnWorker()
            console.log('worker spawned')
        }
    }
}
else {
    console.log('Worker activity')
}
```

*main.js*

```
console.log('Main called')
global.Children = require('./children');
Children.spawn(4)
console.log('Main Finished')
```

*Output from running node main.js*

```
Main called
starting master
spawning worker.....
worker spawned
spawning worker.....
worker spawned
spawning worker.....
worker spawned
spawning worker.....
Main called
Worker activity
```

After this point I get a type error that Children.spawn is not a function and it says Main Finished.

My question is, why is my main.js being called a second time? I just want it to create the worker processes which will in turn listen for events and "stop" execution after it prints "Main Finished". I appreciate any help!

Comment: "Main called" is printed 3 more times right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behaviour, what is forked is the whole process, not only the module from where you call `cluster.fork()`. Workers start their execution from the beginning of the process ;)

Your clustering module should be your main entry point.